# New downloaded softwares don't run

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

I have this problem that whenever I download  a program and I try to run that window appear

**Windows cannot access the specified device,path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.**

So I've done some research and I solve it through changing permissions  on the properties security tab by selecting  everyone to have all permissions and then I have to run it by admin otherwise won't run. Also to note that my previous programs have other parties in the security tab.Which is the fault and how can I overcome this.Thanks in advance.

Sry for not uploading images I am beneath 10 in reputation

EDIT:
seeing this I downloaded now from chrome a software and it works fine so it is firefox's browser issue any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firefox download directory has somehow changed to one where you don't have proper permissions. You can check the default Download directory in Firefox's settings, General screen.

Comment: Thanks its strange when placing it on downloads file it has on the security tab on the groups(SYSTEM,myname,HomeUsers,Adminisrtators) but when on desktop it takes groups(Everyone,Administrators) .Do have any clue why it's that?